# Symfony 3.4 remote authentication

Tags: symfony, authentication

I have the following setup:

- A Drupal page where people login.

  - When they want to go to my Symfony page from Drupal, I attach a "one time hash" in the querystring and redirects them. (The hash is the key to fetch user info)
- On the Symfony page I need to fetch the hash, ask Drupal (via a CURL POST) for the user info.

  - When I've retrieved the userinfo, I need to store it in a cookie for long term storage. I cannot use the hash more than once.

I'm totally lost on this one - it isn't a regular login, it isn't a Remote API Token login either.

I need some kind of authentication, that checks for the cookie - if that isn't found then for the hash in the query. And of course, if none of them is found then redirect them to my Drupal page...

[Edit] I do not have access to the Drupal database or any other DB. Only memcached...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at [GuardAuthentication](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/security/guard_authentication.html#the-guard-authenticator-methods). You can use the `getCredentials()` method to check for the hash and return `null` if not, to skip the rest of the authentication. Then step by step you can load the user, perform the authentication and deal with the success (store it in cookie) or failure (show an error page?).

Comment: Hi dBrumann, That could just be what I'm looking for. I'll have a look - thx.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :-) Thumbs up from me.

Comment: It works now - but every request takes about 6 - 8 seconds? It circles around supports and onAuthenticationSuccess. 

The onAuthenticationSuccess function returns a redirectResponse (Don't know what else to return?) I would just like to show the page that the request object is trying to fetch?

Comment: You could also return `null` in `onAuthenticationSuccess()`. I'm not sure if there is some issue with the redirect or some other part of the guard authenticator being too slow. If you want to find out what is slowing the request down, you could look into the profiler toolbar under performance. Maybe add a new question with a screenshot of the profiler result and some code what your GuardAuthenticator is doing. That would help identifying the issue.